# Combine Promise and EventEmitter

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, eventemitter

I have create this "simple pattern" that works for combine `Promise` and `EventEmitter` (with nodejs).

But: I'm wondering if there is a better way score a goal?

```
const { EventEmitter } = require('events');
const fs = require('fs');

function doSomething(parameters) {
  const emitter = new EventEmitter();

  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // DO DIRTY JOB
    fs.readdir(parameters.directory, (err, files) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
        return;
      }
      files.forEach(file => emitter.emit('update-event', file));
      resolve(`I'm done: ${parameters.param} world`);
    });
  });
  return { promise, emitter };
}

const work = doSomething({ param: 'hello', directory: './' });
work.emitter.on('update-event', data => console.log(`Update ${data}`));
work.promise.then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

I was thinking like:

```
doSomething(...).on(...).then(...)
```

but I can't figure out how do that.

Comment: FYI.. Node V10.0.0 already has [`fsPromises.readdir()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readdir_path_options) functionality which returns a promise.

Comment: You are firing all your events at once - you don't need an `EventEmitter` for that. Just fulfill your promise with an array.

Comment: @Bergi I think he's just showing a simple example and his actual code is more complex where it requires progress events as well as resolving the promise when complete. I'm looking to do something like `doSomething(...).on(...).then(...)` also, but I don't think there's a simple or standardised way to do so - perhaps only by extending the default Promise class and combining aspects of the EventEmitter class.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Node.js has built a function for this: the `require('events').once` function! Here the [PR](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/26078).

It has been released with Node [v11.13] (https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v11.13.0/)

An example usage (from docs):

```
const { once, EventEmitter } = require('events');
async function run() {
  const ee = new EventEmitter();
  process.nextTick(() => {
    ee.emit('myevent', 42);
  });
  const [value] = await once(ee, 'myevent');
  console.log(value); // 42

  const err = new Error('kaboom');
  process.nextTick(() => {
    ee.emit('error', err);
  });

  try {
    await once(ee, 'myevent');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('error happened', err);
  }
}

run();
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'm not sure how the accepted answer is related to the OP's question, anyway I think I do have found a rather simple (but maybe not very nice) way of accomplishing the specific `doSomething(...).on(...).then(...)` thing asked by the OP. Taking the OP's example code, we can just do something like the following:

```
const { EventEmitter } = require('events');
const fs = require('fs');

function doSomething(parameters) {
  var resolves;
  var rejects;
  const emitter = new EventEmitter();
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolves = resolve;
    rejects = reject;
  });
  promise.on = emitter.on;
  promise.emit = emitter.emit;

  // DO DIRTY JOB
  fs.readdir(parameters.directory, (err, files) => {
    if (err) {
      rejects(err);
      return;
    }
    files.forEach(file => promise.emit('update-event', file));
    resolves(`I'm done: ${parameters.param} world`);
  });

  return promise;
}

const work = doSomething({ param: 'hello', directory: './' });
work.on('update-event', data => console.log(`Update ${data}`))
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

It works for my limited cases so far, and both the event and the promise can be chained without issues as far as I know. There might be problems for more complicated use-cases that I have not encountered yet, but it does serve the purpose of chaining `doSomething(...).on(...).then(...)` like the OP asked.

Comment: Very nice solution, thanks for the idea. I needed something similar and you guided me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

No, you shouldn't combine an event emitter and a promise in one object. Returning them separately, just like you did, is fine.

Of course, in your particular example, there's not really a reason to use an event emitter at all. It just fires when the promise fulfills anyway. Much simpler:

```
const fs = require('fs');
function doSomething(parameters) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // DO DIRTY JOB
    fs.readdir(parameters.directory, (err, files) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(Object.assign(files, parameters));
    });
  });
}

doSomething({ param: 'hello', directory: './' }).then(files => {
  for (const data of files) {
    console.log(`Update ${data}`)
  }
  return `I'm done: ${files.param} world`;
}).then(console.log, console.error);
```

Comment: Maybe the example is not so clear, but if I have to create a wrap module over a Class that think in `EventEmitter` way.

For the real world example: the dirty job is manage the `process.spawn` events but I would expose the promise chaining at higher level

Comment: Yes, for that using both an event emitter and a promise is fine.

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest this :

```
import EventPromised from "event-promised";

function doSomething(parameters) {
    return new EventPromised((resolve, reject, emit) => {
        fs.readdir(parameters.directory, (err, files) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            files.forEach(file => emit('update-event', file));
            resolve(`I'm done: ${parameters.param} world`);
        });
    });
}
doSomething({ param: 'hello', directory: './' })
    .on('update-event', data => console.log(`Update ${data}`))
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Hello Matthieu, welcome to StackOverflow! Please make sure to [follow our rules regarding self-promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion), most importantly to disclose in your answer that you're the author of that library. Also please make each answer relevant to the respective question, instead of posting a totally unrelated example (especially since posting the same answer to multiple questions is considered spamming). Please [edit] your posts to fix these issues, then you'll get an upvote from me!